# Postgres error cursor "result_set_a' does not exist inside transaction

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function that returns two cursors based on the data in a temp table:

```
create or replace function public.create_tmp_table(refcursor, refcursor, cid bigint, source_ids bigint[], link_types text[], depth_count integer)
returns setof refcursor
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        create temp table traversed_record_set
        (
          parent_service_item_id bigint, child_service_item_id bigint, link_type text, action_key text, action_date timestamptz
        );
        perform public.link_traversal(cid, source_ids, link_types, depth_count);
        open $1 for (
            select distinct child_service_item_id from traversed_record_set
        );
        return next $1;
        open $2 for (
            select * from traversed_record_set
        );
        return next $2;
    end $function$;
```

When I attempt to open the cursor inside a transaction though I get the error "cursor 'result_set_a' does not exist:

```
begin;
select public.create_tmp_table('result_set_a', 'result_set_b', some_id, array(select some_id), array(select 'some issue type'), 10);
fetch all in "result_set_a";
drop table traversed_record_set;
commit;
```

Comment: Why are so many people using `refcursor` in so many strange ways?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe my attempt here is to be able to return two different result sets from a function. Using a cursor is the only solution I've been able to come up with so far, is there a better solution?

Comment: Why do you need two result sets from one function, especially when one is just a subset of the other?  This is not a common operation in postgres.

Comment: The function is very expensive to run. It builds out a relationship tree by traversing from parent to child links. From this traversal, I need two separate lists (you can see the result set in the function above). The goal is to avoid traversing the tree twice, and instead create a temp table from the traversal and select the two lists from that temp table.

Comment: Then you can use two functions: one that creates a temporary table and returns the first result set, and the other uses the temporary table to return the second result set. I am not saying that your function cannot be fixed to work, but I think it would be easier and less error-prone to do it like I suggest.